# PHP class function naming

Tags: php, class, function, naming

I am having trouble with naming the function. I have a class and I need 2 functions something like below.

```
class myclass {
    public function tempclass () {
        echo "default";   
    }
    public function tempclass ( $text ) {
        echo $text;
    }
}
```

When I call

```
tempclass('testing'); // ( called after creating the object )
```

`function tempclass()` is being called how can i have 2 functions with same name but different parameters?

Comment: Why do you use quote formatting instead of code formatting for your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditional overloading is not currently possible in PHP. Instead you'll need to check the arguments passed, and determine how you'd like to respond.

Check out [`func_num_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) and [`func_get_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) at this point. You could use both of these internally to determine how you should respond to the invocation of certain methods. For instance, in your case, you could do the following:

```
public function tempclass () {
  switch ( func_num_args() ) {
    case 0:
      /* Do something */
      break;
    case 1:
      /* Do something else */
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could provide default values for your arguments as well, and use those to determine how you ought to react:

```
public function tempclass ( $text = false ) {
  if ( $text ) {
    /* This method was provided with text */ 
  } else {
    /* This method was not invoked with text */
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, but suggest editing your answer to include reference links to `func_get_args()` and `func_num_args()`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Overloading isn't possible in PHP.

However, for your simple example above, something like this would work:

```
class myclass {
    public function tempclass ($text='Default') {
        echo $text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Made a change that I think that you may agree with.

Comment: Completely! Didn't even think of that =)

Comment: Your on-line contact form does not work. You live in Scotland, so do I. My contact details are available through this sight.